# NULL as column inside codeignitier active record select?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i try this:

```
 $this->db->select('`LeagueCode`,`DateT`,`HomeTeam`,`AwayTeam`,NULL as `FTHG`,null as `FTAG`,null as `FTR`,null as `HTHG`,null as `HTAG`,null as `HTR`,null as `Referee`,null as `HS`,null as `AS`,null as `HST`,null as `AST`,null as `HF`,null as `AF`,null as `HC`,null as `AC`,null as `HY`,null as `AY`,null as `HR`,null as `AR`,null as `B365H`,null as `B365D`,null as `B365A`,null as `BSH`,null as `BSD`,null as `BSA`,null as `BWH`,
    null as `BWD`,null as `BWA`,null as `GBH`,null as `GBD`,null as `GBA`,null as `IWH`,null as `IWD`,null as `IWA`,null as `LBH`,null as `LBD`,null as `LBA`,null as `PSH`,null as `PSD`,null as `PSA`,null as `SOH`,null as `SOD`,null as `SOA`,null as `SBH`,
    null as `SBD`,null as `SBA`,null as `SJH`,null as `SJD`,null as `SJA`,null as `SYH`,null as `SYD`,null as `SYA`,null as `VCH`,null as `VCD`,null as `VCA`,null as `WHH`,null as `WHD`,null as `WHA`,null as `Bb1X2`,null as `BbMxH`,null as `BbAvH`,null as `BbMxD`,null as `BbAvD`,null as `BbMxA`,null as `BbAvA`,null as `BbOU`,null as `BbMxM25`,null as `BbAvM25`,null as `BbMxS25`,null as `BbAvS25`,null as `BbAH`,null as `BbAHh`,null as `BbMxAHH`,
null as `BbAvAHH`,null as `BbMxAHA`,null as `BbAvAHA`,null as `GBM25`,null as `GBS25`,null as `GBAHH`,null as `GBAHA`,null as `GBAH`,null as `B365M25`,null as `B365S25`,null as `B365AHH`,null as `B365AHA`,
    null as `B365AH`,null as `LBAHH`,null as `LBAHA`,null as `LBAH`,null as `MxH`,null as `MxD`,null as `MxA`,null as `MxO25`,null as `MxU25`,null as `MxAHH`,null as `MxAHA`,null as `AvH`,null as `AvD`,null as `AvA`,null as `AvO25`,null as `AvU25`,null as `AvAHH`,null as `AvAHA`,"1516" as `Season`');
```

i get

> Unknown column 'NULL' in 'field list'

I see that it converts null to

```
 `null`
```

.

So finally it looks like this:

```
SELECT `LeagueCode`, `DateT`, `HomeTeam`, `AwayTeam`, `NULL` as `FTHG`, `null` as `FTAG`, `null` as `FTR`, `null` as `HTHG`, `null` as `HTAG`, `null` as `HTR`, `null` as `Referee`, `null` as `HS`, `null` as `AS`, `null` as `HST`, `null` as `AST`, `null` as `HF`, `null` as `AF`, `null` as `HC`, `null` as `AC`, `null` as `HY`, `null` as `AY`, `null` as `HR`, `null` as `AR`, `null` as `B365H`, `null` as `B365D`, `null` as `B365A`, `null` as `BSH`, `null` as `BSD`, `null` as `BSA`, `null` as `BWH`, `null` as `BWD`, `null` as `BWA`, `null` as `GBH`, `null` as `GBD`, `null` as `GBA`, `null` as `IWH`, `null` as `IWD`, `null` as `IWA`, `null` as `LBH`, `null` as `LBD`, `null` as `LBA`, `null` as `PSH`, `null` as `PSD`, `null` as `PSA`, `null` as `SOH`, `null` as `SOD`, `null` as `SOA`, `null` as `SBH`, `null` as `SBD`, `null` as `SBA`, `null` as `SJH`, `null` as `SJD`, `null` as `SJA`, `null` as `SYH`, `null` as `SYD`, `null` as `SYA`, `null` as `VCH`, `null` as `VCD`, `null` as `VCA`, `null` as `WHH`, `null` as `WHD`, `null` as `WHA`, `null` as `Bb1X2`, `null` as `BbMxH`, `null` as `BbAvH`, `null` as `BbMxD`, `null` as `BbAvD`, `null` as `BbMxA`, `null` as `BbAvA`, `null` as `BbOU`, `null` as `BbMxM25`, `null` as `BbAvM25`, `null` as `BbMxS25`, `null` as `BbAvS25`, `null` as `BbAH`, `null` as `BbAHh`, `null` as `BbMxAHH`, `null` as `BbAvAHH`, `null` as `BbMxAHA`, `null` as `BbAvAHA`, `null` as `GBM25`, `null` as `GBS25`, `null` as `GBAHH`, `null` as `GBAHA`, `null` as `GBAH`, `null` as `B365M25`, `null` as `B365S25`, `null` as `B365AHH`, `null` as `B365AHA`, `null` as `B365AH`, `null` as `LBAHH`, `null` as `LBAHA`, `null` as `LBAH`, `null` as `MxH`, `null` as `MxD`, `null` as `MxA`, `null` as `MxO25`, `null` as `MxU25`, `null` as `MxAHH`, `null` as `MxAHA`, `null` as `AvH`, `null` as `AvD`, `null` as `AvA`, `null` as `AvO25`, `null` as `AvU25`, `null` as `AvAHH`, `null` as `AvAHA`, "1516" as `Season` FROM `odds` WHERE `LeagueCode` = 'SC0' ORDER BY `DateT`
```

I want to remove this quotes from NULL, how can i do that?
I need to use NULL as column because i will use this query for union.

Comment: Why do not use '' as column_name

Comment: because some of columns from first query are not string.

Comment: Those are not quote marks but 'ticks' used to protect field names and values. This can be turned off by adding a second parameter to the select call. Try `$this->db->select('`LeagueCode`, ... ,"1516" as `Season`', FALSE);`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in using null value but may the problem from your framework, so if you use codeigniter you can replace db->select() with db->query('write your complete query here')

Answer (score 0):

Use second parameter

```
$this->db->select('...',false);
```

Comment: You should attempt to explain your solution, not just post code. If there's relevant documentation, it also helps to link to it (remember to quote the relevant section in your answer, too)